# MatrixPlot with Tooltips

Tags: plotting, tooltip

`MatrixPlot` is very nice to have a first look of data, I would like to have a `MatrixPlot` with tooltips for each value. I tried adding `Tooltip` to all the values but it didn't work. My matrix is not very big (~20x25), so each square is visible.

**EDIT:** This is the version I did using the answer of Heike:

```
matPlot[matWithTooltips_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 With[{dim = Dimensions[matWithTooltips], 
   mat = matWithTooltips /. Tooltip[a_, ___] :> a},
  DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}, ij, xy, label, direction},
   direction[mxy_] := 1 - 2 Boole[Thread[mxy > dim/2]];
   LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt],
    Dynamic[
     xy = Floor[pt];
     ij = {dim[[1]], 1} + Cross[xy];
     label = If[And @@ Thread[1 <= ij <= dim],
       {{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thick, LightGray}], Rectangle[xy]},
        Text[
         Framed[Replace[
           Extract[matWithTooltips, ij], {Tooltip[a_, b_] :> b, 
            Tooltip[a_] :> a}], Background -> White],
         direction[xy] + xy,
         -1.2 direction[xy]]},
       {}];
     MatrixPlot[mat, Epilog -> label, opts]],
    AutoAction -> True,
    Appearance -> None]]]
```

The main improvement is that it can receive a matrix with its own tooltips in the data.

Thanks to all for the help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is just an elaboration of faleichik's answer. To create a `MatrixPlot` with tooltip labelling and highlighting of the selected square similar to for example `BarChart` or `BubbleChart` you could do something like

```
matPlot[mat_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 With[{dim = Dimensions[mat]},
  DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}, ij, xy, label, direction},
   direction = 1 - 2 Boole[Thread[# > dim/2]] &;
   LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt],
    Dynamic[xy = Floor[pt];
     ij = {dim[[1]], 1} + Cross[xy];
     label = If[Nand @@ Thread[1 <= ij <= dim], {},
       (* else *)
       {{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thick, LightGray}], Rectangle[xy]},
        Text[Framed[mat ~Extract~ ij, Background -> White],
         direction[xy] + xy, -1.2 direction[xy]]}];
     MatrixPlot[mat, Epilog -> label, opts]],
    AutoAction -> True,
    Appearance -> None]
   ]]
```

**Screenshot**

```
mat = RandomReal[1, {30, 40}];
matPlot[mat, ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors"]
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Very nice! Looking to the code: is there any particular reason to use `With[]` wrapping here? Why not include `dim = Dimensions[mat]` directly to `DynamicModule`? Am I missing something?

Comment: @faleichik No particular reason other than that `With` is usually more efficient for localizing constants than `DynamicModule` (although I don't think it would make any noticeable difference in this case).

Comment: I like this a lot, but something I don't like is that when I changed the tooltip for something more complex, it got cut by the borders, maybe it could be fix to change the position of the tooltip towards the center of the image. I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: @FJRA You can increase `ImagePadding` to prevent the labels from being cut off by the borders.

Comment: I inserted a simple direction function instead of `1+xy` and worked very nice! `direction := 1 - 2 Boole[Thread[# > dim/2]] &` and changed `1+xy` -> `direction[xy]+xy`, `{-1.2,-1.2}` -> `-1.2 direction[xy]`.

Comment: Why do I even bother to answer `Graphics` questions? +1 :-)

Comment: Perhaps, this is also the approach to answer [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1146/125) long-standing question on changing the position of `Tooltips`?

Comment: I made a couple of changes.  Revert if you dislike them.

Answer (score 21):

My variant is without tooltips but is fast. You need to click on the desired cell to get the value. One more advantage is that you have the generic `MatrixPlot`, not a substitute.

```
A = Table[Sin[x y/10 + x], {x, 1, 50}, {y, 1, 50}] // N;
{n, m} = Dimensions@A;
DynamicModule[{pt = {1, 1}/2, trans, ij},
 trans[{x_, y_}] := {Max[1, Min[n, Floor[n - y] + 1]],
   Max[1, Min[m, Floor@x + 1]]};
 Column@{
   LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], MatrixPlot[A, ImageSize -> 500]], 
   Dynamic[(ij = trans@pt) -> A[[Sequence @@ ij]]]
   }
 ]
```

[image]

---

EDIT: more dynamic version without `LocatorPane` (no need to click) + using `Clip` as Mr.Wizard kindly adviced.

```
   A = Table[Sin[x y/10 + x], {x, 1, 50}, {y, 1, 50}] // N;
   {n, m} = Dimensions@A;
    DynamicModule[{pt = {1, 1}/2, trans, ij},
     trans[{x_, y_}] := {Clip[Floor[n - y] + 1, {1, n}],
       Clip[Floor@x + 1, {1, m}]};
     Column@{MatrixPlot[A, ImageSize -> 500],
       Dynamic[(ij = trans@MousePosition["Graphics", {0, 0}]) -> 
         A[[Sequence @@ ij]]]}
     ]
```

---

EDIT 2: using Appearance->None and Epilog, creating a stylish Tooltip in the right place, with the right alignment (you can probably do more to style it better if you want to spend the time).

```
A = Table[Sin[x y/10 + x], {x, 1, 50}, {y, 1, 50}] // N;
{n, m} = Dimensions@A;
DynamicModule[{pt = {1, 1}/2, trans, ij}, 
 trans[{x_, y_}] := {Max[1, Min[n, Floor[n - y] + 1]], 
   Max[1, Min[m, Floor@x + 1]]};
 gLoc[{x_, y_}] := {First@#, 1 + n - Last@#} &@Reverse@trans@{x, y};
 Column@{LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
    MatrixPlot[A, ImageSize -> 500, 
     Epilog -> 
      Dynamic@{EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[None], 
        Rectangle[gLoc@pt, gLoc@pt - 1], EdgeForm[Black], 
        FaceForm[{Opacity[.7], RGBColor[1, 1, .6]}], 
        If[First@gLoc@pt < n - 12,
         {Rectangle[gLoc@pt + {6, 2}, gLoc@pt + {-1, 0}], 
          Text[A[[Sequence @@ (trans@pt)]], gLoc@pt + {2, 1}]},
         {Rectangle[gLoc@pt + {-7, 2}, gLoc@pt], 
          Text[A[[Sequence @@ (trans@pt)]], gLoc@pt + {-3, 1}]}]}], 
    Appearance -> None, AutoAction -> True], 
   Dynamic[(ij = trans@pt) -> A[[Sequence @@ ij]]]}]
```

Comment: Technically not tooltips, but quite possibly the better alternative. +1

Comment: Noted.  You may care to know there is a built-in function for the `Max[ Min [ ] ]` thing: `Clip[. . ., {1, m}]`

Comment: I like this approach. You could set `AutoAction -> True` in `DynamicModule` if you want the locator position to be continuously updated. Also, to mimic `Tooltip`, you could play around with `Appearance` in `LocatorPane`, or use `Epilog` to dynamically plot a label with the current value on top of the matrix plot.

Comment: This is a very good alternative, since I can locate the "tooltip" above and use it as title comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: y-axis corrected

You could do something like this:

```
a = RandomInteger[99, {7, 5}];

minmax = {Min@a, Max@a};
cf = ColorData["SunsetColors"];
ticks = Table[{i, # - i + 1}, {i, #}] & @ Length[a]

Graphics[
 {cf[1 - Rescale[#2, minmax]],
    Tooltip[Rectangle[# - 0.5], #2]} & @@@
      Most @ ArrayRules @ Reverse[a\[Transpose], {2}],
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {All, ticks}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1. It is VERY hard to make something faster than you guys. Although this `Tooltip` aproach becomes very slow for large matrices.

Comment: @faleichik it is slow, but unless there is a specialized option for `Raster` I am overlooking I don't know of a better way.

Comment: I thought also about doing my own matrix plot, anyway I wanted to know if `MatrixPlot` could be adapted to have tooltips. Here would be necessary to add the `MatrixPlot` behavior for non numeric cases (like `Indeterminate`). Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

One can also use the option `CoordinatesToolOptions` for `MatrixPlot` and make use of the `Get Coordinates` tool as follows:

```
 MatrixPlot[mat, ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors",
 CoordinatesToolOptions -> 
 {"DisplayFunction" ->
 Function[pt, 
 With[{rows = Dimensions[mat][[1]], columns = Dimensions[mat][[2]]},
 indices = {Clip[Floor[rows - pt[[2]]] + 1, {1, rows}], 
    Clip[Floor@pt[[1]] + 1, {1, columns}]};
  Row[{"mat[", Row[indices, ","], "]  =  ", Extract[mat, indices]},
   Background -> White, ImageSize -> {150, 30}, 
   Alignment -> Center]
  ]]}]
```

where I used faleichik's transformation.

Screenshot:

[image: tooltip and get coordinates]

**Update:** Generalizing, one can

- Embed the needed coordinate transformations into  `DisplayFunction` option for tooltips, and into `CopiedValuesFunction` option for copy/paste,
- Use these user-specified functions as values for the `CoordinatesToolOptions` option in `MatrixPlot`, and
- Let the `Get Coordinates` tool manage the dynamics needed for tooltips and copy/paste

as in:

```
  mtrxPlot2[mat_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  With[{dims = Dimensions[mat], 
  indx = {Clip[Floor[#1[[1]] - #2[[2]]] + 1, {1, #1[[1]]}], 
  Clip[Floor[#2[[1]]] + 1, {1, #1[[2]]}]} &}, 
  With[{copiedvalues = "CopiedValueFunction" -> Function[pt,
  {indx[dims, pt], Extract[mat, indx[dims, pt]]}], 
  coordtooltips = "DisplayFunction" -> Function[pt,
  Row[{"mat[[", Row[indx[dims, pt], ","], "]]  =  ", 
    Extract[mat, indx[dims, pt]]},
   Background -> White, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 30}, 
   ImageMargins -> {{5, 5}, {10, 10}}, Alignment -> Center]]}, 
  MatrixPlot[mat, opts, 
  CoordinatesToolOptions -> {coordtooltips, copiedvalues}]]]
```

Comment: This is really cool and a best answer IMO.

Comment: @faleichik, thank you. I like your and Heike`s `LocatorPane` approach better because it allows you to highlight the cells (which I do not know how to do with `CoordinatesToolOptions`)

Comment: After trying it, I think it's very fast, but I had a problem, when using the output of this graphic into a `GraphicsGrid`, it looses the custom coordinates tooltips. Anyway this is the fastest one!

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this:

```
is = 150; rm = RandomInteger[100, {5, 5}]; m =  Map[Tooltip[#, #] &, rm, {2}];
A = GraphicsGrid[m, ImageSize -> is {1, 1}]; B =  MatrixPlot[rm, FrameTicks -> None, 
Mesh -> All, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> is {1, 1}]; Overlay[{A, B}, All, 1]
```

[image]

It'll be a bit more elaborate to add frame ticks.

Comment: Good option, but tooltips only show up when you are in the center of the squares (if they are bigger than text numbers behind). I like that this is simple enough to be done without references once you know it :P.

Comment: @FJRA Yes, thanks. `Overlay` is neat but often overlooked function - plus it preserves interactivity ;)