# How to improve this code for exploring large matrices?

Tags: plotting, dynamic, matrix

What I'm actually trying to do is to elaborate [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2512/219). I'd like to use `Pane` with scrollbars enabled to explore large (sparse) matrices like this one:

[image]

Here is what I have so far using some ideas from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2524/219):

```
A = ExampleData[{"Matrix", "HB/west0381"}, "Matrix"] // Normal;
{n, m} = Dimensions@A;
mp = MatrixPlot[A, ImageSize -> 9 m, Mesh -> All];
DynamicModule[{trans, ij, mpos},
 trans[{x_, y_}] := {Clip[Floor[n - y] + 1, {1, n}],
   Clip[Floor@x + 1, {1, m}]};
 Pane[
  Show[mp, ImagePadding -> {{40, 20}, {20, 20}},
   Epilog -> Text[
      Framed[
       Dynamic[(ij = trans@MousePosition["Graphics", {0, 0}]) -> 
         A[[Sequence @@ ij]]], Background -> White],
      Dynamic[MousePosition["Graphics", {0, 0}]],
      {1, -1}
      ]~Style~Larger
   ],
  {500, 500},
  Scrollbars -> True]
 ]
```

The result is

[image]

---

**Now about the problems**

**1.** The main trouble is that it does not correctly translate coordinates
for horizontal scrolling. If we don't touch the horizontal scrollbar
everything is fine:

[image]

But if I slide horizontally the label shifts and falls outside the
visible area. It looks like a Mma bug.

**2.** The second funny thing is that if I remove `//Normal` from the first row then   `MatrixPlot` produces the following:

[image]

which seems to be the second bug.

**3.** And finally the issue which is due to my confusion with `Dynamic` things. In the code I use `MousePosition["Graphics", {0, 0}]` twice (can this be the reason for the item 1 from above?). When I tried to save this coordinates in a variable I had no luck. But there must be a way to do this.

---

**SUMMARY**

Thanks to Andy for resolving problems number 2 and 3, and to David for nice solution using `MouseAnnotation`. I accept kguler's answer since it resolves the main problem with runaway tooltip by effectively using `CoordinatesToolOptions` option. Here is complete working example with kguler's solution. Try it (to enable the tooltip right-click on  the plot and select "Get Coordinates"):

```
mtrxPlot2[mat_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 With[{dims = Dimensions[mat],
   indx = {Clip[Floor[#1[[1]] - #2[[2]]] + 1, {1, #1[[1]]}], 
      Clip[Floor[#2[[1]]] + 1, {1, #1[[2]]}]} &}, 
  With[{copiedvalues = 
     "CopiedValueFunction" -> 
      Function[pt, {indx[dims, pt], Extract[mat, indx[dims, pt]]}], 
    coordtooltips = 
     "DisplayFunction" -> 
      Function[pt, 
       Row[{"mat[[", Row[indx[dims, pt], ","], "]]  =  ", 
         Extract[mat, indx[dims, pt]]},
        Background -> White,
        ImageSize -> {Automatic, 30},
        ImageMargins -> {{5, 5}, {10, 10}},
        Alignment -> Center]]},
   MatrixPlot[mat, opts, 
    CoordinatesToolOptions -> {coordtooltips, copiedvalues}]
   ]
  ]

A = ExampleData[{"Matrix", "HB/west0381"}, "Matrix"];
Pane[mtrxPlot2[A, ImageSize -> 3000, Mesh -> All, 
  MaxPlotPoints -> 500], {500, 500}, Scrollbars -> True]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `mtrxPlot2` from my answer to [the cited question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2512/219) inside `Pane`

```
   Pane[mtrxPlot2[A, ImageSize -> 9 m, Mesh -> All], {500, 500}, 
   Scrollbars -> True]
```

one cane exploit the built-in tooltip and copy features of the `Get Coordinates Tool` (clicking on the graph and hitting "." or using the context menu).

```
mtrxPlot2[mat_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
With[{dims = Dimensions[mat], 
indx = {Clip[Floor[#1[[1]] - #2[[2]]] + 1, {1, #1[[1]]}], 
Clip[Floor[#2[[1]]] + 1, {1, #1[[2]]}]} &}, 
With[{copiedvalues = "CopiedValueFunction" -> Function[pt,
{indx[dims, pt], Extract[mat, indx[dims, pt]]}], 
coordtooltips = "DisplayFunction" -> Function[pt,
Row[{"mat[[", Row[indx[dims, pt], ","], "]]  =  ", 
Extract[mat, indx[dims, pt]]},
 Background -> White, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 30}, 
 ImageMargins -> {{5, 5}, {10, 10}}, Alignment -> Center]]}, 
MatrixPlot[mat, opts, 
CoordinatesToolOptions -> {coordtooltips, copiedvalues}]]]
```

Screenshot:

[image: matrix plot in pane with tooltips]

Comment: A wonderful solution. Could you paste the full working code here for convenience?

Comment: @faleichik, thank you very much. I added the copy of the code.

Answer (score 7):

**MouseAnnotation**

You could use `MouseAnnotation` to display the results under the pane. It is immune to the bugs you mention and has less overhead than a tooltip.

```
A = ExampleData[{"Matrix", "HB/west0381"}, "Matrix"] // Normal;
{n, m} = Dimensions@A;
trans[{x_, y_}] := {Clip[Floor[n - y] + 1, {1, n}], Clip[Floor@x + 1, {1, m}]};

Pane[MatrixPlot[A, ImageSize -> 9 m, Mesh -> All], {500, 500}, 
     Scrollbars -> True]

Dynamic@MouseAnnotation[(ij = 
 trans@MousePosition["Graphics", {0, 0}]) -> A[[Sequence @@ ij]]]
```

I removed `Show`, `ImagePadding` and `Epilog` from the original code (including one instance of `MousePosition`--the one used to position the `Text`).

---

**Edit**
The picture below shows the cursor at Row 18, Col 20.  The mouse annotation, at the bottom left of the pic, shows that that Row 18, Col 20 of A has the value, -2.04109.  **The position, (row 18, col 20) corresponds to the coordinate (20, 18), not (18, 20)**.

[image: cursor at row 18 col 20]

Now let's ask A to confirm the value for that entry:

```
A[[18, 20]]

(* Out *) -2.04109
```

This works is the same manner for all columns, including those that have to be reached via the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: This does not solve the problem of coordinates translation though. Anyway a big +1 for `MouseAnnotation`.

Comment: @faleichik Strange. It solves the coordinates translation problem on my machine. (Mac OSX 10.7.7, mms 8.0.4). And I was having the problems before the fix.

Comment: David, forgive me for the confusing formulation. By "coordinates translation problem" I meant incorrect position of tooltips after horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 6):

The solution to the second problem is easy. You can increase `MaxPlotPoints` to something larger (or just set it to `Infinity`). Seems that the method for choosing them automatically doesn't do so well with a large `SparseArray`.

**Edit:**

Part 3 can be accomplished by re-writing your `Epilog` as such..

```
Epilog -> 
  Dynamic[ij = MousePosition["Graphics", {0, 0}]; 
   Text[Framed[(trans@ij) -> A[[Sequence @@ (trans@ij)]], 
      Background -> White], ij, {1, -1}]~Style~Larger]]
```

Comment: Andy, what was the OP doing incorrectly in his `Epilog` that your edit fixes?

Comment: @rcollyer they weren't doing anything incorrectly but they requested a solution that only used `MousePosition` a single time.

Comment: Sorry, I misread his question.

Comment: Thank you, Andy. I didn'n expect that the second issue can be resolved that easy. This solution is somehow hard to guess. Looking to your solution of the part 3 I feel ashamed :-)