# Nothing happens when I click the mouse clicked on my graphics

Tags: dynamic, image-processing, image, plotting

I wrote codes to record list of coordinates when mouse clicked. It is expected that the coordinates should be plotted dynamically. But actually nothing happened. Can anybody help me to find the reason?

```
i = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
dgray = ImageData[i, Interleaving -> False][[2]];
iedge = EdgeDetect[i, 5];
igray = Image[dgray];
dmorc = MorphologicalComponents[iedge];
imorc = Image[dmorc];

DynamicModule[{ncurve = {}}, 
  EventHandler[
    ImageCompose[
      igray, 
      Graphics[ListLinePlot[ncurve, Axes -> False]]], 
    {"MouseClicked" :> 
       (ncurve = 
          PixelValuePositions[imorc, 
            PixelValue[imorc, MousePosition["Graphics"] /. None -> {0, 0}]])}]]
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference to your previous questions: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63319/131 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60911/131?

Comment: I solved the raised error issue, discard the trans[] function, and correct the point coordinates. Now the only issue is no response.

Comment: It's totally different now as it is only a grammar issue, I think. Please let it post openly. I really need somebody's help.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step in debugging is always to narrow down the problem. To do this, you can make `ncurve` global:

```
DynamicModule[{(* ncurve = {} *) }, 
 EventHandler[
  ...
```

Then, you can click on the image and evaluate `ncurve` in a separate cell:

```
Length[ncurve]
```

> 248652

(You can and should put `ncurve` in a `DynamicModule` once you're done, of course. But for debugging, it's common practice to make local variables global and play with them in another notebook cell.)

Now you a lot more than just "nothing seems to have happened": You know that

1. `ncurve` was set, but the display wasn't updated. That's the easy part: You just have to wrap the `ImageCompose[...]` part with `Dynamic[...]` and it's updated dynamically. (`DynamicModule` localizes variables, like `Module`, it doesn't make the contained code block dynamic, like `Dynamic`.)
2. those are way too many points. In fact, unless you (accidentally) manage to hit one of the few edge points in the image, `ncurve` will simply contain all the black points in the edge-image. (Which could easily hang or crash the Mathematica Frontend.)

That's because the `imorc` image is zero for all non-edge pixels. What you would need is an image that contains a unique index for each connected component, *or the index of the closest connected component, if it's a background pixel.* Here, `WatershedComponents` is very useful:

```
watersheds = 
  Image[WatershedComponents[ColorNegate[iedge], Method -> "Basins"]];
imorc = Image[ImageData[watersheds] * ImageData[iedge]];
```

Now, if you use `PixelValue[watersheds, ...`, you get a component index, for edge- and non-edge pixels, and you can use `PixelValuePositions[imorc, ...` to look up the corresponding edge pixels:

```
DynamicModule[{(*ncurve={}*)}, 
 EventHandler[
  Dynamic[ImageCompose[igray, 
    Graphics[
     ListLinePlot[ncurve, 
      Axes -> False]]]], {"MouseClicked" :> (ncurve = 
      PixelValuePositions[imorc, 
       PixelValue[watersheds, 
        MousePosition["Graphics"] /. None -> {0, 0}]])}]]
```

Now, if you click on the image, you see a superimposed edge line. But it's probably not what you expected:

[image]

If you don't understand what you're seeing, try evaluating `ListLinePlot[ncurve]` alone. `ListLinePlot` chooses a `PlotRange` that fits the list of points, and `ImageCompose` simply composes the two resulting images, ignoring the different coordinate systems. What you really want is `Show`:

```
DynamicModule[{(*ncurve={}*)}, 
 EventHandler[
  Dynamic@Show[igray, 
    ListLinePlot[ncurve]], {"MouseClicked" :> (ncurve = 
      PixelValuePositions[imorc, 
       PixelValue[watersheds, 
        MousePosition["Graphics"] /. None -> {0, 0}]])}]]
```

[image]

Also: `EventHandler` is a relatively low-level function. Mathematica has higher-level functions like `LocatorPane` that can make your life simpler:

```
DynamicModule[{mousePt = {1, 1}},
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[mousePt],
  Dynamic[
   Show[igray, 
    ListLinePlot[
     PixelValuePositions[imorc, PixelValue[watersheds, mousePt]]]]]]]
```

One last note: I've learned to avoid dynamic code during debugging as much as possible. I've lost too much work because the notebook interface hung or crashed evaluating a programming error (e.g. like displaying a list plot with 248652 points). Use a `LocatorPane` to choose a point, and a separate non-dynamic cell with `Show`, `Graphics`, `ListPlot` and friends until you're satisfied with the result. *Then* put them in a dynamic block. (Or actually, save your notebook, *then* put them in a dynamic block.)

Comment: Thank you,nikie. Your detailed answer really helps me a lot.