# Highlighting individual 'cells' in Matrix/ArrayPlot

Tags: graphics, visualization, plotting

I am plotting some matrices / arrays via `MatrixPlot` and `ArrayPlot`, and I would like to highlight several of the cells via outlining. Perhaps something like this (but less dramatic)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I've been playing around a little bit with settings for `Mesh` but it's a little unruly because it doesn't seem designed to allow specification at this level.

My evil desires would be to have a sort of `HighlightFunction` option that would make a decision to highlight the cell or allow a `Highlight` specification in `ArrayPlot` or `MatrixPlot`.

I know I can hand-roll this, of course, but was wondering if anyone had a solution 'out of the box' before I start.

The `ToolTip` inspired version linked below is a start at this but not a straight-forward solution for doing multiple, simultaneous highlights.

Comment: Also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2512/12

Comment: @Szabolcs et al.,  I __think__ I'm asking a different sort of question re: simultaneously highlighting several cells w/o the manual intervention / tooltip method in the above. That is, it's not clear to me how to do this via that proposed mechanism.

Comment: Check the link at the top of the post where it says "This question already has an answer here:"!  The tooltip thing is just an additional post I linked to which may or may not be of interest to you.

Comment: Ah hah- right. Sorry. Didnna see that on first shot. I must have just done a really bad search to not find that. Thank you.

Comment: Well, even when I remember that there was a duplicate, often I just cannot find it.