# How can I combine 2D slider with MatrixPlot?

Tags: matrix, slider

If I enter `MatrixPlot[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]`，it shows:[image]

How can I combine this with a 2D slider，when I move the slider to a region，it could show me the value that correspond to the matrix?

Comment: See the answers [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2512/9490)

Comment: By "slider", do you actually mean "tooltip"?

Comment: @J.M. - I actually like faleichik's `Dynamic` version in the linked post (duplicate?) better than the `Tooltip`-based accepted answer

Comment: I think it's a dupe, @Jason, but I'll let other people vote... and yes, faleichik's solution is lovely.

Comment: I hadn't seen the first comment, excuse me.

Comment: @BoLe - No worries at all.  I think it's often more fun to come up with an answer before closing a duplicate

Comment: Thank you  JasonB. I found your link more useful

Answer (score 2):

By "slider", do you mean locator?

```
m = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {10, 10}];

With[{eps = .1},
 DynamicModule[{p = {.5, .5}, lab},
  lab[{x_Integer, y_Integer}] :=
   Style[StringJoin[{"value: ",
      ToString[m[[Length[m] - y, x + 1]]]}], 16, Bold];
  LocatorPane[
   Dynamic[p],
   MatrixPlot[m,
    PlotLabel -> Dynamic[lab@Floor@p]],
   {{eps, eps}, Dimensions[m] - eps}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I want! Amazing! Thank you very much.