# Change Location of Tooltip

Tags: tooltip

The following code produces a tooltip for the string "parabola":

```
Tooltip["parabola", 
 Panel[Style[
   TextCell[
    "A parabola is a symmetrical open plane curve formed by the intersection of a cone with a plane parallel to its side. The path of a projectile under the influence of gravity ideally follows a curve of this shape."], Background -> LightGreen], Background -> LightGreen,
   ImageSize -> {250, Automatic}]]
```

[image]

I'd like the popup to appear above the string "parabola" (rather than below and to the right). Is it possible to control the placement of tooltips?  I can't seem to find any options to control this.  I can build a custom one using an attached cell, but this won't work for me as the Wolfram Cloud does not support attached cells.  It does support tooltips.

For reference...
Solution Using an Attached Cell:

```
Button[Style["parabola", "Text"], 
 obj = AttachCell[EvaluationBox[], 
   Panel[Style[
     TextCell[
      "A parabola is a symmetrical open plane curve formed by the intersection of a cone with a plane parallel to its side. The path of a projectile under the influence of gravity ideally follows a curve of this shape."], Background -> LightGreen], Background -> LightGreen,
     ImageSize -> {150, Automatic}], Top, 8, Bottom, 
   RemovalConditions -> "MouseExit"], AutoAction -> True, 
 Appearance -> None]
```

Also for reference....Solution Using Mouse Appearance:

```
Dynamic@MouseAppearance[
  Annotation["parabola", 
   Panel[Style[
     TextCell[
      "A parabola is a symmetrical open plane curve formed by the intersection of a cone with a plane parallel to its side. The path of a projectile under the influence of gravity ideally follows a curve of this shape."], Background -> LightGreen], Background -> LightGreen,
     ImageSize -> {150, Automatic}], "Mouse"], 
  MouseAnnotation[], {0.5, -1}]
```

Comment: there does not seem to be an option to change location of tooltip.

Comment: If the window is at the bottom it pops up above the location. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jso1.gif) screenshot. And I don't know how to force its location.

Comment: Related to [1146](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1146/can-the-position-of-tooltips-be-changed).

Comment: You can make one with AttachCell.

Comment: Yes, according to John Fulz, it's not possible.  I posted a solution using an attached cell and another using mouse appearance but neither work in the Woflram Cloud.  A tooltip solution would have been nice.